# Similarity between binary vector with hierarchal structure

Tags: scikit-learn, metric, distance, scipy

I have dataset of binary vectors, where each vector composed from several small vector coming from a different parent category.

Each of those categories has a different size e.g. `101 category A` `111100 category B` -> union `101111100 combined vector`

From previous studies, it seems like Jaccard similarity is working best for each small vector - but when combining them the distance makes less sense because of the different sizes, and needs to be normalized.

What would be the best way to?

Normalizing the vectors beforehand means I'll have to switch metric, and averaging the distance from each is not feasible productwise.